# Installing an Oven - Microwave combo

Tags: electrical, oven

I am replacing a double oven.  1974 model tappan.  The new combo has 4 wires, red, white, black and green.   The wall / supply is a Romex wire with white, black and bare.    The new unit, Frigidaire FGMC2765PFK has the microwave plugged in to the top of the oven.   How do I connect the wires for proper operation?

Comment: What is the wattage stated by the nameplate on the device?  The manual won't say, it says "look at the nameplate".

Comment: Is the supply run from the main panel, or from a subpanel?  How hard would it be to pull a wire from the panel to the oven junction box?

Comment: It would be nearly impossible to pull another wire.  I believe it is directly from the main panel.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the junction box then?

Comment: There is no junction box.  Just a Romex wire with White, black and a bare wire.Not sure how to post a photo.

Comment: Is there *any way at all* you can get a wire from that location back to the panel?

Comment: Don t think that is possible.

Comment: @tony There is **always** a way. It just may not be very practical or affordable.

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of digging through the Frigidaire site, but I found [the specifications page](http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Specsheets/FGMC2765P_0917_EN.pdf).

Key points:

> Voltage Rating 240V/208V/60Hz
>
> Connected Load (kW Rating) @ 240/208 Volts 6.9/5.2
>
> Minimum Circuit Required (Amps) 30

and

> Single phase 3- or 4-wire cable, 120 / 240 or 120 / 208 Volt, 60 Hertz AC only electrical supply with ground required on separate circuit fused on both sides of line.

- *Circuit required* - it says 30 Amps. This is confirmed by [the installation manual](http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Memphis/807611001.pdf) which covers many models but says for an appliance rating between 4801W and 7200W (6.9kW = 6900W), circuit recommended = 30A. This is actually a good thing as it is quite likely that the existing circuit for your Tappan was 30A or larger. If so, the wires should be OK (except for the **number** of wires...), though you may actually need to downsize the breaker if it is currently a 40A breaker.
- *Wires required* - it says 3 or 4. However, the installation manual (see bottom of page 3 and top of page 4) makes it quite clear that a 3-wire connection is only OK if (a) **permitted by local code** (it is typically grandfathered in, but not recommended, and possibly **forbidden** for a new appliance installation, and in any case not a good idea) **and** (b) the 3rd wire must be a **neutral** - i.e., a full size insulated current carrying wire, NOT a bare ground as you currently have.

**Bottom line: You need at least one new wire.** New oven needs 2 hots, neutral, ground. Old oven was either:

- 2 hots plus ground - need another wire for neutral
- 2 hots plus neutral combined with ground - not safe

If all you need to do is add one wire and the existing wires are in conduit then you can do that. If they are a *cable* then you will usually replace it with a new black /red /white /ground cable of the appropriate size.

If you add a wire to conduit, I believe (Harper or one of the other pros can confirm), you should actually use the existing *white* wire as neutral and add a different color (typically *red*, but anything not white, gray or green is OK) for the 2nd hot.

Comment: No it is not required to replace the wiring! Code allows the existing wiring to be used. The black and white are usually hot in this case. They would connect to the red and black.

Comment: @EdBeal I agree, provided (a) it is in conduit (so another wire can be added), which appears to be the case based on "supply is a loose wire" and (b) it is big enough, which unless the previous oven was really wired wrong (e.g., 12 AWG), should not be a problem, as ovens even in 1974 typically used 30 A. But my understanding is that white should always be neutral in a conduit (except at really large sizes), in which case white should become neutral and a **new** wire should be added to be the 2nd hot (replacing white).

Comment: I have seen a lot of built in ovens that were direct wired from the romex it would look like a loose wire in that case. This was very common in that time frame.

Comment: Took me a minute to realize what you meant - i.e., the existing "loose wires" might really be Romex. But if that's the case, then (normally) no conduit, in which case you can't just add a single extra wire (for the missing neutral) which means (as was the case when I replaced my single oven with a double and needed to go up from 30A to 40A), a new NM cable of the appropriate size and /3.

Comment: Since it was a double oven I would expect the wire gauge will be sufficient, then the question would be the max breaker size required by the MFG.

Comment: Agreed. The big questions are (a) what is the current breaker - which should be trivial to find out - and it is either < 30 - upgrade, 30 (perfect!) or > 30 and (b) what size are the current wires - if 10 AWG then should be fine, if smaller then *replace*, (c) are the existing wires in a conduit (add a wire) or not (*replace* with /3). Right now, as usual, we are guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I am away from the house right now, so I can not identify the Romex size (quite thick though) or the breakers.  It is a double breaker though, I just do not remember the size.    I think it would be nearly impossible to pull a new wire through the studs to the panel.  The previous oven was wired (oven to supply- Red to white. Black to black.  White and Green to Bare.

Comment: @tony It is a pretty good bet (but not guaranteed) that the existing breaker is 30A and hopefully the wire is at least 10 AWG to match. So there is a half-decent chance that is all OK. The problem is that while using a neutral wire to *also* carry ground is no longer approved but sometimes grandfathered, doing the opposite - which is what you have - using a ground to carry neutral adds an additional safety issue. Grounds (especially *bare* ones) are not designed to carry current on a regular basis, they are designed for *emergency* situations, and that is not "grandfathered in" in any way.

Comment: I just remembered that there is a 110 outlet nearby that powers the trash compactor.  Should I run a lead from there in order to connect the white to white?

Comment: No!!!! That is permitted for grounds(retrofit ground) but if you mix neutrals you **WILL** overload the neutral the first time you use the oven and a high current appliance on the 110 at the same time. Neutral is not breakered, only hot. This would actually be worse than your existing setup.